# How to make a child element disappear after drop?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have 2 divs (dragdiv1, dragdiv2) and each of them contains another div with a text. I'm dragging a photo from another div back and forth between the first 2 divs mentioned and when I drop the photo into one of them, I want the text disappear and then appear again when photo is dragged into the other div.

I'm *very new to this* so I'm kind of struggling to achieve it. Can someone give me a hint how to make it?

This is what I have so far, but no disappearing happens, so it's probably completely wrong, or am I at least somewhat close to my intention?

HTML part:

```
<div class="photo">
   <img src="blahblah.jpg" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="drag1"></img>
</div>

<div id="0" class="dragdiv1" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
    <div class="draganddroptext">Drag&Drop Area</div>
</div>

<div id="1" class="dragdiv2" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
    <div class="draganddroptext">Drag&Drop Area</div>
</div>
```

Javascript attempt:

```
function allowDrop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
}

function drag(ev) {
    ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
}

function drop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
    ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
    var off = document.getElementsByClassName('draganddroptext');
    if (off.style.display == "none") {
        off.style.display = "inline";
    } else {
        off.style.display = "none";
    } 
}
```

--- update

```
function drop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
    ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
    var targetId = ev.target.id;
    var targetElems = document.getElementsByClassName('draganddroptext');
    var off;
    var on;
    if (targetId == 0) {
        off = targetElems[0];
        off.style.display = "none";
        on = targetElems[1];
        if (on.style.display == "none") ){
            on.style.display = "inline";
        }
    } else {
        off = targetElems[1];
        off.style.display = "none";
        on = targetElems[0];
        if (on.style.display == "none") ){
            on.style.display = "inline";
        }       
    }           
}
```

Any help is highly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

getElementsByClassName returns an array of elements. So to control the visibility of your elements you have to include which element you want to hide e.g.:

```
var off = document.getElementsByClassName('draganddroptext');
off[0].style.display = "none"; //hides first element
```

You already have your target element so you can just get the relevant element by calling:

```
var off = ev.target.getElementsByClassName('draganddroptext')[0];
if (off.style.display == "none") {
    off.style.display = "inline";
} else {
    off.style.display = "none";
}
```

Comment: ok thanks, I get it, but I still cannot make it work. I'm trying to reference the correct drop target in order to hide or show the correct text, but I probably do it wrong. I tried various things and this one looked the best but now it's doing completely nothing. can you please check the updated javascript if you find what I'm missing please?

Comment: not even dropping works, don't know how I messed it up that much :x

Comment: I think the problem is in "targetId"... from your HTML your elements only have class not id so ev.target.id would be null or undefined. If you add IDs to your elements I think that would make your code a lot easier to implement.

Comment: oh yeah I actually did that but forgot to update that part in my code here.. it's still not working tho